# Templated Priority Queue inheriting from templated Heap

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, heap, priority-queue

I'm trying to write a priority queue for my programming class but continue to get the following errors:
PriorityQueue.cpp:7:1: error: ‘PriorityQueue::PriorityQueue’ names the constructor, not the type
PriorityQueue.cpp:7:1: error: and ‘PriorityQueue’ has no template constructors

I've been at it for several hours now and have no idea whats wrong. Here is the code it is referring to:

```
template < typename DataType, typename KeyType, typename Comparator >
PriorityQueue<DataType,KeyType,Comparator>
    ::PriorityQueue<DataType,KeyType,Comparator>( int maxNumber )
        : Heap<DataType,KeyType,Comparator>( int maxNumber )
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
template < typename DataType, typename KeyType, typename Comparator >
PriorityQueue<DataType,KeyType,Comparator>
    ::PriorityQueue( int maxNumber ) // <-- removed unneeded template parameter
        : Heap<DataType,KeyType,Comparator>( maxNumber ) // <--- maxNumber should be a parameter to the base class, not a definition.
{

}
```

Comment: thanks, this makes it compile. :) we weren't given a lot of instruction on any of this and we went over inheritance last year so the syntax is fuzzy